# Importing an image as grayscale and converting it to grayscale doesn't produce the same result when multiplying it by 255

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I'm currently working on a project to isolate a number plate from an image.

When I import an image using `cv2.imread("filename",0)` the grayscale image I obtain is more or less the same (maybe a few rounding differences due to the fact that I convert it to integers.) To when I import it using `cv2.imread("filename")` and then convert it to grayscale using `np.dot(original_image[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.144])`.

However, when I multiply both `ndarrays` with `255` I do not obtain the same output matrices. Both grayscale images are of the same dimensions, produce the same output when I convert them to a figure, are of the same type and produce the same `otsu` threshold. Why does this happen? Does OpenCV display and save image `ndarrays` differently?

How can I manipulate the second grayscale image to produce the same output as the first grayscale image after multiplying it with 255?

```
def func():
    rgb_image=cv2.imread('filename')
    gray_image=cv2.imread('filename',0)

    rgb_converted_to_gray_image=np.dot(rgb_image[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.144])

    print("Before multiplying with 255")
    print(gray_image)
    print("------------")
    print(rgb_converted_to_gray_image)

    gray_image=gray_image*255
    rgb_converted_to_gray_image=rgb_converted_to_gray_image*255

    print("After multiplying with 255")
    print(gray_image)
    print("------------")
    print(rgb_converted_to_gray_image)
```

The output is as follows:

Before multiplying with 255

```
[[32 29 34 ... 92 88 86]
 [33 28 32 ... 85 85 86]
 [35 29 28 ... 85 93 99]
 ...
 [ 8  8  8 ... 32 32 32]
 [ 8  8  8 ... 32 32 32]
 [ 8  8  8 ... 33 33 33]]
------------
[[ 27.512  24.721  29.129 ... 105.014 100.894  98.989]
 [ 29.14   23.99   27.069 ...  97.804  97.804  99.432]
 [ 30.912  25.02   23.547 ...  98.701 106.797 112.977]
 ...
 [  9.292   9.292   9.292 ...  33.558  33.558  33.558]
 [  9.292   9.292   9.292 ...  33.558  33.558  33.558]
 [  9.292   9.292   9.292 ...  34.588  34.588  34.588]]
```

After multiplying with 255:

```
[[224 227 222 ... 164 168 170]
 [223 228 224 ... 171 171 170]
 [221 227 228 ... 171 163 157]
 ...
 [248 248 248 ... 224 224 224]
 [248 248 248 ... 224 224 224]
 [248 248 248 ... 223 223 223]]
------------
[[ 7015.56   6303.855  7427.895 ... 26778.57  25727.97  25242.195]
 [ 7430.7    6117.45   6902.595 ... 24940.02  24940.02  25355.16 ]
 [ 7882.56   6380.1    6004.485 ... 25168.755 27233.235 28809.135]
 ...
 [ 2369.46   2369.46   2369.46  ...  8557.29   8557.29   8557.29 ]
 [ 2369.46   2369.46   2369.46  ...  8557.29   8557.29   8557.29 ]
 [ 2369.46   2369.46   2369.46  ...  8819.94   8819.94   8819.94 ]]69.46  ...  8819.94   8819.94   8819.94 ]]
```

Thus, what I would like is for the last matrix to look the same as the one above it.

Comment: “are of the same type“ No, they’re not. One is 8-bit integer and one is a floating-point type. You need to convert the integer one to float before multiplying.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks you for the help! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons due to which the difference in results is being observed.

1. Difference in data-type
2. Channel order

The first reason, as pointed out by @Cris Luengo in a comment is the data type difference between `gray_image` and `rgb_converted_to_gray_image`. `gray_image` has type `uint8` whereas `rgb_converted_to_gray` has type `float32`. As a result of multiplication by 255, the values of `gray_image` are scaled to the range of `uint8`. To get around this issue, you can do floating point multiplication just by changing `255` to `255.0`.

```
gray_image = gray_image * 255.0
```

Now comes the second issue. Even if we do floating point multiplication, the results will be different because OpenCV images are stored in channel order `BGR` by default, while you are providing the gray-scale conversion coefficients in `RGB` order. Also, the coefficient for blue value is incorrect. It should be `0.114` instead of `0.144`. To verify the logical correctness of RGB coefficient values, check that their sum should be equal to 1. The corrected coefficients array should be like this:

```
[0.114, 0.587, 0.299]
```

The final code may look like this:

```
def func():
    rgb_image=cv2.imread('filename')
    gray_image=cv2.imread('filename',0)

    rgb_converted_to_gray_image=np.dot(rgb_image[...,:3], [0.114, 0.587, 0.299])

    print("Before multiplying with 255")
    print(gray_image)
    print("------------")
    print(rgb_converted_to_gray_image)

    gray_image=gray_image*255.0
    rgb_converted_to_gray_image=rgb_converted_to_gray_image*255

    print("After multiplying with 255")
    print(gray_image)
    print("------------")
    print(rgb_converted_to_gray_image)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and quick reply. I appreciate it!